# PIV Certificate issue with VSCODE

Tags: git, cac

Banging my head.  Cannot find the solution to solve using **VSCODE** pull/push to GIT.
Git commands work fine on command line.

> Missing or invalid credentials. Wrong number of arguments fatal:
> unable to access 'https://repository.com/git/SOME_repo/': NSS: client
> certificate not found: LAST.FIRST.MIDDLE.1234567890:PIV ID Certificate

Comment: You need to tell us more about your setup.  What operating system are you on?  What version of Git are you using?  Are you using any special Git integration with VS Code?  What is PIV?  What are relevant details about your setup with certificates?  What kind of server are you trying to push to?  Anything that might be relevant to us in helping explain your problem should be included in your question.

Comment: (Redhat 7 Desktop) Linux 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 12 14:08:31 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: (Redhat 7 Desktop) Linux 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 12 14:08:31 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

'Push to Redhat & server

git version 1.8.3.1

Git Extensions for VS Code 1.1.2
Git History 0.6.6

(.gitconfig)
[http]
 sslCaInfo = /home/username/.pki/nssdb/xxx-root-certs.pem
 sslverify = true

personal identity verification
CAC, PIV, and Smart Card. ... These are also known as a common access card (CAC), a personal identity verification (PIV) card, and a smart card. All three are used for authentication.'

Comment: All of this should be edited to be in your question, especially the command output which should be in a code block.  It's impossible to read in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

> /VSCode-linux-x64/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh

(hard coded pin works... but not secure)

```
echo '123456'
```